# Terraform modifying existing Route53 record instead of inserting new record

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a zone here:

```
resource "aws_route53_zone" "example_com" {
  name = "example.com"
}
```

An existing TXT record here:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "example_com_txt" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example_com.zone_id
  name    = "example.com"
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [
    "v=spf1 foo ~all",
    "google-site-verification=zzzz",
    "google-site-verification=bbbb",
    "other-things",
    "MS=ms12345",
    "apple-domain-verification=abcd12345"
  ]
}
```

Trying to add this TXT record:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "easydmarc_txt" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.example_com.zone_id
  name.   = "_dmarc.example.com"
  type    = "TXT"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:somename@somedomain.us, mailto:dmarc-reports@example.com; ruf=mailto:somename@ruf.somedomain.us; fo=1"]
}
```

When I attempt to run `terraform plan -target module.route53.aws_route53_record.easydmarc_txt`, it appears to be attempting to modify the existing TXT record:

```
  # module.route53.aws_route53_record.easydmarc_txt must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_route53_record" "easydmarc_txt" {
      + allow_overwrite = (known after apply)
      ~ fqdn            = "example.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id              = "Z0N3ID_example.com_TXT" -> (known after apply)
      ~ name            = "example.com" -> "_dmarc" # forces replacement
      ~ records         = [
          - "MS=MS=ms12345",
          - "apple-domain-verification=abcd12345",
          - "google-site-verification=zzzz",
          - "google-site-verification=bbbb",
          - "other-things",
          + ""v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:somename.somedomain.us, mailto:dmarc-reports@example.com; ruf=mailto:somename@ruf.somedomain.us; fo=1",
          - "v=spf1 foo ~all",
        ]
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

I'm not understanding why it's trying to modify the existing record.

Comment: You appear to already have a `aws_route53_record.easydmarc_txt` resource in your state file. You have modified the definition so to TF this is an intended modification of that resource.

Comment: Also to be clear, that's not an edit of the existing record. It will delete the existing record and replace.

Comment: @jordanm thanks for the reply. I removed the resource from state, imported it, and ran plan again. Same result.

Comment: Why did you import it?

Comment: Because the record exists in Route53.

Comment: I am not understanding what you're expecting at this point. If the resource is the the statefile and you make modifications to it, it will edit the resource except in the case that something you have edited is immutable, in that case it is forced to delete and replace the existing resource.

Comment: @jordanm I've figured out the issue. I was not importing it correctly, which was causing it to modify the example.com TXT record instead. If I had shown my syntax for my "import" command, it would have been obvious to you. Either way, you are correct in your answer. Thanks for your efforts!

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to figure out your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The TXT record I was adding was an existing record in Route53. My `terraform import` command was incorrect, causing terraform to modify the `example.com` record instead.

Changed:

```
terraform import module.route53.aws_route53_record.easydmarc_txt Z0N3ID_example.com_TXT
```

To:

```
terraform import module.route53.aws_route53_record.easydmarc_txt Z0N3ID__dmarc.example.com_TXT
```

terraform plan now works as expected.